# Valid members of polymorphic array of an Interface type

Tags: java, class, oop, polymorphism

Following is a sample class design that I hope will help me ask this question:

```
public interface Foo 
{
    int someMethod();
}

public abstract class Bar implements Foo 
{
    public int someMethod()
    {
       return 1;
    }
}

public class Baz extends Bar 
{

}

public class Quz extends Bar 
{
    public int someMethod()
    {
       return 2;
    }
}

public class Norf extends Baz 
{
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        Foo[] arr = new Foo[4];

        // Some code to take advantage of polymorphism
    }
}
```

In the `Norf` class , I have created a polymorphic array of type `Foo` (which is an interface). I was trying to understand objects of which classes are allowed to be a member/element of this array.

From what I understand , if you are making a polymorphic array of a class , than any objects created from its sub-class (any of its descendant in the inheritance tree) can be a member of this array.

I am trying to formulate a rule for a polymorphic array of an interface.

Coming back to sample class design , the following seems to valid (I typed this out in my IDE and it did not complain)

```
    arr[0] = new Baz();
    arr[1] = new Quz();
    arr[2] = new Norf();
```

So it looks like objects of any non abstract class that implements the interface or any of it's concrete sub classes can be a member of this array.

Is there anything that I am missing or anything that can be added to the above rule ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Expanding on @karthik's answer, any instance that implements `Foo` can be an element of the array. And a class implements `Foo` either directly or, indirectly, by being a descendant of a class that implements it or by being a descendant of a descendant of a class that implements it, etc etc.

Or it could also happen that an interface extends `Foo` and then a class implements this subinterface; then it would be also valid for an instance of such a class to be an element of the array:

```
public interface SubFoo extends Foo { }

public class Blablab implements SubFoo {

    public int someMethod() {
        return 3;
    }
}
```

A few examples:

```
Foo[] arr = new Foo[7];
arr[0] = new Baz();
arr[1] = new Quz();
arr[2] = new Norf();
arr[3] = () -> 7; // As Foo has only one method, lambdas are allowed as well
arr[4] = new Bar() {}; // Anonymous classes are also allowed
arr[5] = new SubFoo() { public int someMethod() { return 123; } };
arr[6] = new Blablab();
```

Answer (score 1):

Any class that is implements `Foo` interface or any class which extends a class, which implements `Foo` directly or indirectly can be added.

In your case

```
arr[0] = new Baz();  // Baz extends Bar and Bar implements Foo
arr[1] = new Quz();  // Quz extends Bar and Bar implements Foo
arr[2] = new Norf(); // Norf extends Baz, Baz extends Bar and Bar implements Foo
```

If you draw a tree kind of structure

```
             Foo
              |
             Bar
            /   \
           Baz   Quz
           /
           Norf
```

All the classes you have defined directly or indirectly implements the interface `Foo` so all of them can be added.